# User name not getting to database

Tags: asp.net

I am using the following to store the current user name in a variable that is passed to my stored procedure and then to my database.  This is initiated with a button click.

```
string UserName = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

The variable is sent with this command:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
```

I have created a web form in Web Developer 2008 Express, and when I display the browser in Web Developer I get the desired results.  When I run the web page from my native browser (Firefox) running on a Mac, I get nothing.  Web Developer is running on a Windows 2008 Server installation.  Do I need to do something different for Macs?  I will have a majority of users who will use Mac rather than Windows.

Here is the code from the aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void MasterData_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=(local);database=InvoiceSHC;Trusted_Connection=Yes"))
            {

                // Get the UserId of the logged in user 

                string UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                string Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                //Not sure why you need a SqlDataAdapter unused here.
                //SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("UpdateSHCInvoice", con);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateSHCInvoice", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ref", dlRef.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhaseName", dlPhase.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageType", dlPageType.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page", tbPage.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percent", dlPercent.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChngType", dlChngType.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timestamp",Timestamp);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                GridView1.DataBind();

            }



        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are they logging in somehow magically, or do you have any real login procedure, making sure `Page.User`'s value makes sense?

Comment: are the other values are entering into the database and can you show us the entire database connection how you're trying to do?

Comment: I edited the original post since comment area is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that the user is *not* authenticated when accessing the page from a browser on another computer, but *is* authenticated when accessing from the server.  You can check this for sure by setting the username like this:

```
string UserName = "";
if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
}
else
{
    UserName = "UnauthenticatedUser";
}
```

If I am correct, then you need to double check your authentication procedure (web.config, etc).  Let me now if you have any questions.

Comment: jadarnel27 - I ran it with your code and when running in web developer, I received the correct results.  When run in Firefox I received UnauthenticatedUser.  Should this authentication process be moved to the page load event rather than the button click?  From a logic standpoint once they bring the page up they are done from a user id standpoint.

Comment: @TimVavra Good, that makes sense. What type of authentication are you using? In your web.config, look under "`<System.web>`" and "`<authentication>`" - what does it say next to "mode"?

Comment: It says <authentication mode="Windows"/>.  The code above it has a <!--   this be <authentication>  My HML coding skills are almost non existent but I thought there was always a precursor / postcursor relationship.

Comment: jadarnel27 - I made a change to the authorization in IIS.  I removed the anonymous authentication.  This will require the user to login using their AD account.  If they do not login, no web site.  I think this will work very well for what I have to do.  I am going to leave your code in place, so I can catch any instances where authorization does not occur.  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @TimVavra Sorry, I was offline for a bit.  Good work, changing in IIS is exactly where I would have gone from there.  lad I could point you in the right direction =)

Comment: I am getting unauthorized users now when I log in and I do not get asked for my user name and password when I go to the web site.  Any ideas?

Comment: @TimVavra Have you double checked that the authorization settings you changed have not been reverted somehow?

Comment: I have disabled anonymous authentication.  I have windows authentication and asp.net impersonation enabled.

Comment: @TimVavra And nothing else has changed?  I just find it confusing that all the sudden it stopped working.  Perhaps something in your web.config got modifed by accident?

Comment: 2I can send you the web.config if you think that would help.  I have had to go back and make changes to the web page several times.  The only thing that seemed to happen is that I would lose my default page in IIS and would have to reestablish it before I could continue.

Comment: @TimVavra I don't think the web,config would help, no.  Based on your last sentence, I'm just a little concerned that something is intermittently modifying your IIS settings.  But I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: I removed the asp.net impersonation and I can get to everything except the user name.  Right now if I run the site from Web Developer - using view in browser, I get the user name.  I think that this is because my server is running windows with IE.  When I run it locally, I am using mac os with firefox.  The frustration comes in the fact that the windows authentication showed up the first time but does not come up any more.  I have tried multiple combinations of the authentication types without success.

Comment: I will keep at it.  If I have to I will put a drop down box on the form and have the users select their name when they enter the information.  It doesn't have the same security but it will work until I can figure the rest of it out.  Could the operating system have anything to do with it?  I know that MacOS uses keychains and maybe that is somehow affecting how this is working.

Comment: I had a couple of issues going on at the same time.  First I had my web site in two different folders which was very confusing as to how it happened in the first place.  I found this when I was looking at the app pool and saw two sites for the app pool I was using.  Second, I failed to reestablish the default start page.  Since I only have one page, it should be simple, but IIS does not assume anything and I did not tell it what my default page was so I would get a 401 or 404 error.  Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Comment: @TimVavra Wow, you were really getting hit from all sides there.  Glad you got it worked out, and that I was able to help in some capacty.  It's always to tough to figure out a problem when there's more than one thing happening at once.